# word-wrap: break-word; not breaking the <code></code> tag

Tags: html, css

i have an issue with the word-wrap break-word property, it is supposed to break the code tag
that when it hits the border of

```
<div>class="link alert clearfix"</div>
```

but it is not breaking the word, it instead jumps down on the next line, next to the "voting" div

Here is the issue:

http://meetthemes.com/post/?post=Mooncraft+-+Themeforest+Premium+Theme

Scroll down to the third download link, thats the one that jumps down

Answer (score 9):

If you set it to `display: inline-block` and give it a `max-width`, it will break the word for you. You'll also need to remove the `white-space: nowrap` on the code element in your CSS, or disable it for your specific `code.link` class, by adding `white-space: normal`.

Answer (score 4):

John suggestion not work at all, in order to work you must use also the properties entitled in this post:

So use below sample code:

```
<code style="display: inline-block;white-space: normal;max-width:100%; word-break:break-all; word-wrap:break-word;">anyyyyyyyylonnnnnngggggggggstringggggggggwillllbetrunnncateeeeeddddddd</code>
```

You can set any max-width, in integer PX, EM or by percentage nor just simply do not set a max-width, as it is not mandatory